# Passing lock between thread

Tags: c++, multithreading

If I have the a workflow like the one below.

```
somelock;

thread1: somelock.lock();

thread1: ...

thread1: start thread2;

thread1: somelock.unlock();

      thread2 start : somelock.lock();
      thread2:...
      thread2: somelock.unlock();
```

With the condition that:

1. only `thread2` can acquire the lock after `thread1` unlock.
2. after `thread2` unlock(), any one have access to `somelock` have a chance to acquire the lock.

As if the lock has been pass from `thread1` to `thread2`. 
Is it achievable using C++?

Comment: Looks like homework Yes it is. :)

Comment: You are mixing paradigms of "unit of work" and "thread". If you want to chain work in this way, there is no point in switching threads. Just execute the 'thread2 work' at the desired point within your current thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> only thread2 can acquire the lock after thread1 unlock.

Your pseudo-code doesn't guarantee the above condition. A mutex alone won't do the trick. A more complex approach is required:

```
std::mutex mtx;
std::condition_variable cond;
bool thread2_done = false;

void thread1()
{
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> guard(mtx);

    // do some work with mtx locked

    start_thread2();
}

void thread2()
{
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> guard(mtx);

    // do some work with mtx locked

    thread2_done = true;
    cond.notify_all();
}

void thread3()
{
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> guard(mtx);
    cond.wait(guard, [] { return thread2_done; });

    // do some work with mtx locked
}
```